# Flyback energy from coil flows back to source (high power pulse generator)

Tags: oscillator, flyback

I am charging a coil to 2A, then (after BJT off) I want transfer this energy to cap to get a rounded L2 coil pulse (voltage). The coil pulse will be used to wireless signal transfer.
This generator is in discontinued mode so after about 2us coil charging and 1us coil discharging it takes about 120us to "refresh" C1 voltage thru 220k to be able to generate a next pulse (battery saving).
Everything is fine except during coil flyback some energy flows thru BJT (reversed) to source (see scope picture).
I am ok with the first "peak down" due to BJT in linear region but I have no idea what is going on with the "wide flatness down".

Any idea?

**Current drawn from source:(gnd in a middle)**
[image]

**L2 voltage (gnd in a middle):**
[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvawCD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Edit:**
Regarding the layout you probably did not see any worst. However, the important wires (LC tank, supply) are short and thick enough.
The Vcc is bypassed with about 200u ceramic so the supply is pretty stable.
Now the point. I got an old soviet scope that sometime shows 50Hz in ripple. Maybe that is a thing. In combination that I measure the drawn current on 220mohm shunt connected in Gnd path during switch off there should be no voltage across shunt and the scope can shows a "nonsense" , so the second flat reverse current do not has to be truth. It is rippled after zooming, btw.

However, I have no idea how to measure it.

Photo of layout:

[image]

**Edit2:**

I did a LTspice simulation. There is no backflow current in results. So most probably it is just scope malfunction.
Or LTspice is too idealized :)

Simulation of drawn current thru 220mohm resistor:
[image]

Comment: Could you show layout?

Comment: What's the white stuff, painted steel? Looks like you're able to solder to it? It's hard to follow wires, could you highlight the photo with connections and components? (Include probe locations.) Where is current being measured? (Not with a current probe I suppose; but I don't see an obvious shunt resistor, either.)

Comment: @TimWilliams The board is from wood and it is painted with white color. The shunt is a power resistor where the alligator clip (from scope) is connected. So the one side of shunt is GND and another the common of L2,R4,C2,R3. I will try to rearrange it and get here a new photo.

Comment: What's the time scale here? Could this be a diode junction in reverse recovery?

Comment: @Hearth The timescale on scope screen pics is 0.5us/div. A reverse recovery of a diode would apear at the end of D1 conduction, but the flatness in waveform is during all energy transfer from L2 to C2 (first schematic)(about 1us).

Comment: Next best guess: induction from the open-field (rod) inductor to the wiring (probes included). Does it change with probe wire positioning?

Comment: You might try adding some leakage inductance for your coupled coils. Simulation may then reveal something.